# Calling callback function inside for loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run a callback function inside a for loop, but I am finding issues in executing the callback function. Seems like the function gets executed after the for loop is completed. For example if for loop has 2 iteration, then the function is executed only after the two for loop iteration is executed. Hence the execution of function is always done after the last iteration of for for loop. I am trying it really hard and have spend almost a day today looking at examples and have finally have used the closures as per the example provided in example in below link but still not getting the accurate result.
https://www.geekabyte.io/2013/04/callback-functions-in-loops-in.html

Below is the code that I am using :

```
            let promoList = [];
            for(i = 0; i< availablePromoCount; i++){

              promoObj = {};
              promoObj.maxUsesUser = getAvailablePromoResults[i].MaxUsesUser //getAvailablePromoResults is a list coming from another function not shown here

              promoObj.promoCode = getAvailablePromoResults[i].PromoCode; // available promo code for this iteration

              promoList.push(promoObj);

              (function(clsn){
              
                  searchUserUsedPromo(userId, promoList[clsn].promoCode, (error, searchUserUsedPromoResults) => {
                    if (error) {
                      console.log(error);
                      return res.status(500).json({
                        success: 0,
                        message: "Some other error",
                        error: error,
                      });
                    }
                    console.log("Iteration of function is ", clsn);  // always iteration is last iteration and displays same and last iteration of i
                    
                    console.log("Searched promo code is ", promoList[clsn].promoCode);
                    timesUsed = searchUserUsedPromoResults.length;
                    console.log("Times Used", timesUsed);
                    console.log("Max uses user", promoList[i].maxUsesUser);

                  });
              
              })(i)

              count++;
              if(getAvailablePromoResults.length == count){
              
                return res.status(200).json({
                  success: 1,
                  availablePromoList: availablePromoList,
                });

              }
            }
```

searchUserUsedPromo() calls order.model.js to get the db query and executes

```
searchUserUsedPromo: (userId, promoCode, callback) => {
    pool.query(
      `select * from userpromo where UserId = ? and PromoCode = ? and Used = 1`,
      [
       userId, 
       promoCode
      ],
      (error, results, fields) => {
        console.log(results);
        if (error) {
          return callback(error);
        }
        return callback(null, results);
      }
    );
  },
```

Comment: Is searchUserUsedPromo an async function ?

Comment: I've never heard of the function `cosnole.log`. Is this some new NodeJS API? (Line 22 of your code)

Comment: @ElheniMokhles After each for loop iteration , i wanted to call the function searchUserUsedPromo . So i wanted for loop to wait until searchUserUsedPromo . Hope that answers your question.

Comment: @code Its a typo, its console.log , just for logging. I have fixed that

Comment: Uh, yeah.  The loop doesn't wait for the callback function.  It's asynchronous.  That means that all your loop does is initiate the search and then immediately go onto the next iteration of the loop.  Then, some time later (after the `for` loop is completely done), the search finishes and calls the callback.  This structure will not work at all.  Beset to "promisify" your asynchronous operation so you can then use `async/await` with it.  The loop will pause for `await` on a promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you please help me on it on where to apply the promisify or await on my code, as I am less experienced.

Comment: @aasirkhan - Can you show the code for `searchUserUsedPromo()`?  Does it have native promises inside it?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated my description to include what it does now. Basically it calls model class and fetch db query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop doesn't wait for the callback function. It's asynchronous. That means that all your loop does is initiate the search and then immediately go onto the next iteration of the loop. Then, some time later (after the for loop is completely done), the search finishes and calls the callback. This structure will not work. Best to "promisify" your asynchronous operation so you can then use async/await with it. The loop will pause for `await` on a promise.

Based on the partial code you've shown in your question, here's a promisified version that allows the loop to wait for the asynchronous operation:

Summary of Changes:

1. `searchUserUsedPromo()` has been changed to return a promise
2. Your main code block has been turned into an `async` function that uses `await when calling` searchUserUsedPromo()`so that the`for` loop will pause
3. Centralized error handling in one place
4. Complete is in one place (doesn't need to use a counter any more)
5. Add `let` to declare all variables used here

And, here's the code:

```
// promisify this function so it returns a promise that resolves/rejects
// when it is complete and resolves with the asynchronously retrieved value
searchUserUsedPromo: (userId, promoCode) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(`select * from userpromo where UserId = ? and PromoCode = ? and Used = 1`,
            [userId, promoCode], (error, results, fields) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(results);
                }
            }
        );
    });
},


async function someFunction(req, res) {
    try {
        let promoList = [];
        for (let clsn = 0; i < availablePromoCount; clsn++) {

            let promoObj = {};
            //getAvailablePromoResults is a list coming from another function not shown here
            promoObj.maxUsesUser = getAvailablePromoResults[clsn].MaxUsesUser

            // available promo code for this iteration
            promoObj.promoCode = getAvailablePromoResults[clsn].PromoCode;

            promoList.push(promoObj);

            let searchUserUsedPromoResults = await searchUserUsedPromo(userId, promoList[clsn].promoCode);
            console.log("Iteration of function is ", clsn);
            console.log("Searched promo code is ", promoList[clsn].promoCode);
            let timesUsed = searchUserUsedPromoResults.length;
            console.log("Times Used", timesUsed);
            console.log("Max uses user", promoList[i].maxUsesUser);
        }

        res.status(200).json({
            success: 1,
            availablePromoList: availablePromoList,
        });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({
            success: 0,
            message: "Some other error",
            error: error,
        });
    }
}
```